# Continue to render component while leave transition is active

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a component with a value that constantly changes. However, when it’s hidden with a transition, it stops updating the value, which is not the behavior I want.

Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hdodov/5vu7wgj8/) or this snippet:

```js
var demo = new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data: {
    visible: true,
    counter: 0
  },
  created: function() {
    setInterval(function() {
      this.counter++;
    }.bind(this), 200);
  }
});
```

```css
.fade-enter,
.fade-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
}

.fade-enter-active,
.fade-leave-active {
  transition: 2s ease;
}

[v-cloak] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://vuejs.org/js/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="demo" v-cloak>
  <p>Value: {{ counter }}</p>

  <transition name="fade">
    <p v-if="visible">Transition: {{ counter }}</p>
  </transition>

  <button @click="visible = !visible">
    Transition!
  </button>
</div>
```

As you can see, when you click the button, the fading paragraph freezes at the current counter value, while the other one continues to update. **How do I avoid that?** I want the fading paragraph to stop updating the value only when it’s *completely* hidden, when the transition has finished.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to complement @Sandwell's answer and @Nope's comment,

You can remove the element after the transition is completed.

http://jsfiddle.net/jacobgoh101/5vu7wgj8/4/

```
<p v-show="visible" v-if="exists" @transitionend="handleTransitionend">
```

and

```
new Vue({
    data: {
        // ...
        exists: true
    },
    methods: {
        handleTransitionend() {
            this.exists = false;
      }
    }
});
```

---

**UPDATE:**

@HristiyanDodov built a complete solution on top of @Sandwell's and my suggestions, by making use of [transition hook](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#JavaScript-Hooks) `@before-enter` and `@after-leave`.

**This is the complete solution:** http://jsfiddle.net/hdodov/5vu7wgj8/6/

Comment: While the transition button doesn't seem to add the element again this is addressing OPs request now. Changed to upvote.

Comment: It breaks if you click the button before the transition has finished. Just mash the button a couple of times in quick succession and see. Good idea, though.

Comment: That update didn’t work. If you click the button just a single time, it fades out, but `exists` remains `true`. Check out [my update](http://jsfiddle.net/hdodov/5vu7wgj8/6/) - I have solved this problem via the `before-enter` and `after-leave` events. It also works correctly when you rapidly click the button. Put my fiddle in the answer and I’ll accept it.

Comment: @HristiyanDodov I think you can answer it yourself. As it's not really my answer. thanks

Comment: Well, I found that solution thanks to you, so you deserve the credit in my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

It freezes because `v-if` triggers the `destroy` event so the component does not exist and it can not be binded anymore.

Use `v-show` instead of `v-if`

[Proof of Concept](http://jsfiddle.net/5vu7wgj8/2/)

Comment: Your code is not doing what OP asked `I want the fading paragraph to stop updating the value only when it’s completely hidden, when the transition has finished.` - Your code keeps updating the value even after the transition is done and the element is hidden. Inspect console to see it.

Comment: The data counter can not be unbinded, he has to create a new var and update it when a click on transition button is triggered.

Comment: The solution should be updating the counter until the element is hidden then stop updating it. Either way, your solution doesn't do that. I'm also not sure it is good for memory if a hidden element is updated indefinitely.

Comment: @Nope no offense at all ! sorry about this. just that after reading this article https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/ , i agree that people on stackoverflow cares about being right much more than anything else. and the tone of voice can just seems cold sometimes

Comment: @JacobGoh Emotions are hard to translate in dead-text on a screen. Better to focus on facts and logic then side tracking in the possible "tone". Future users with similar programming issues don't care for "drama" they want working solutions. Edit: Also that blog-post, while it has a point, is going a bit overboard with the dramatics in my personal opinion.